# How to get most closest match with Table A from Table B in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to match row by row with Table A [aparties] from Table B [bparties] which is not associated Table, they are different tables and want to get most closest matches with DateTime, A_Number, B_Number and Duration.

when i tried with convention of Cakephp3, it shows "Aparties is not associated with Bparties" with "InvalidArgumentException" because they are not related each other.

[image: Please check my Tables]

Results should look like

[image: Results]

I tried to get a result

```
    $aparties = $this->loadModel('aparties');
    $bparties = $this->loadModel('bparties');


    $results = $aparties->find()
        ->select(['start_time', 'a_number', 'b_number', 'duration', 'b.start_time', 'b.a_number', 'b.b_number', 'b.duration'])
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->join([
            'table' => 'bparties',
            'alias' => 'b',
            'type' => 'inner', // Tried also with 'cross', 'left' but no luck
            'conditions' => [
                'b.b_number = aparties.b_number',
                'b.a_number = aparties.a_number',                    
            ]
        ]);
```

But This matches a few rows where both values are available but the closest Number were not found when same b_number and a_number available in both Tables.

Thanks for your helping & guiding me in advance.

Comment: If you don't have well structured data might you consider re-evaluating your table design or doing the comparisons outside of SQL in just PHP?

Comment: Thanks a lot @systematical, Probably i have to work with PHP after getting the result from SQL though i don't know the way yet. :)